# How to rename a Linked Service in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am new to ADF and need some help please.
I created a Linked service for a sql database. I know need to make this dynamic (I know how to do this). I also want to rename the Linked service to reflect this dynamic nature.  But I cannot find a way to do this.
Can someone help please? Not many hits in a google search
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If your ADF is linked to GIT you can follow these simple steps to rename your linked Service:

1. Clone your ADF locally
2. Create a new branch (optionally)
3. Open ADF code in any Editor and Search and replace Linked Service name in all files (I use VSCode)
4. Rename Linked Service file name to new name (If not done ADF will prompt an issue)
5. Commit and push your changes
6. Verify on ADF (don't forget to switch branch)
7. Create a pull request to merge your changes to your main branch

Comment: That works well for me!https://www.connorkirkpatrick.com/2018/06/06/how-to-rename-a-linked-service-in-azure-data-factory/

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't rename a Linked Service after it is published. If you want to dynamically create a linked service I would suggest building a small script using the SDK:s that are available like the `ArtifactsClient` from `azure-synapse-artifacts` for Python if you're running in Synapse Analytics Data Factory. You might then want to create a Linked Service for each run and tear it down after you've ran your pipelines. There should be an SDK for this in  the "regular" Data Factory as well.

EDIT: Just noticed that there's a function for renaming a linked service through the mentioned API. See documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-synapse-artifacts/azure.synapse.artifacts.operations.linkedserviceoperations?view=azure-python-preview#begin-rename-linked-service-linked-service-name--new-name-none----kwargs-).

Comment: Yes, that is what I am finding as well that you cannot rename.  Thank you